# How does DirectMap1G affect the number of hugepages?

Tags: dpdk

I have been able to set the default huge page size to 1GB using the GRUB command line in /etc/default/grub however it seems that I can't set the number of hugepages greater than 12 no matter how I do it (either boot commands or sysctl).  It looks like the DirectMap1G parameter is exactly 13 times the size if my hugepagesize (DirectMap1G=13631488kB, and hugepagesize=1048576kB).  Is there any way to increase the size of the DirectMap1G parameter if that is what is limiting the number of hugepages?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

DirectMap1G is a kernel space measure, i.e. hugepage mapping for kernel usage.

DPDK is a userspace library, so instead you need to reserve hugepages for userspace usage as described in [DPDK Getting Started Guide](http://dpdk.org/doc/guides/linux_gsg/sys_reqs.html#running-dpdk-applications).

So correct kernel options would be like following:

```
default_hugepagesz=1G hugepagesz=1G hugepages=4
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Do you know of a good explanation of what the parameters in /proc/meminfo mean?